# @font-face, Javascript vs CSS

Tags: javascript, css, font-face

I'm wondering if anyone has had any experience comparing the performance of @font-face fonts from a font service that requires referencing via Javascript ( such as typekit ) vs. a font service that requires referencing via CSS ( fontdeck ).

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since they both have to use CSS, obviously adding JavaScript to it can only make the process take more time ([CETERIS PARIBVS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ceteris_paribus)).